# DBMS_LOB.substr returns null

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, clob

`v_tmp_clob := DBMS_LOB.substr(v_qry_strng, dbms_lob.getlength(v_qry_strng)-10,1);`

the previous line returns null though `v_qry_strng` is a CLOB of length 32897 characters ... can any one explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified Oracle version.

`DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` returns a `VARCHAR2` (among others, but not `CLOB`), which can hold at most 32767 bytes worth of characters.

Also, `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` returns `NULL` on the [following conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349):

1. Any parameter is explicitly NULL
2. Param 2 (amount) < 1
3. **Param 2 (amount) > 32767**
4. Param 3 (offset) < 1
5. Param 3 (offset) > `LOBMAXSIZE`

In your expression, you have: `dbms_lob.getlength(v_qry_strng)-10` --> `32897-10` --> `32887` as param 2.

`32887 > 32767` <-- This is why.

---

Update:

To copy from LOB to LOB directly, use [`DBMS_LOB.COPY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i997674).

In your example, it could be like:

```
DBMS_LOB.COPY(v_tmp_clob, v_qry_strng, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_qry_strng) - 10, 1, 1);
```

Comment: so how to do the same on CLOB in my case ?

Comment: With `DBMS_LOB.COPY`, the parameters are slightly different ,but it'll be easy. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i997674